Analytic functions not running in Sybase
I am very new to Sybase (my first time actually after moving from the Oracle & Snowflake).
My question :  Does Sybase allow any analytic function (RANK, ROW_NUMBER, SUM() OVER etc)?
I am using Sybase version :
Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP04 PL01 HF2/EBF 30229 SMP/P/x86_64/SLES 12.4/ase160sp04pl01x/3488/64-bit/FBO/Tue Feb  8 20:54:55 2022

Where can I find a list of available functions that will work with above Sybase version ?

while Sybase SQLAnywhere and Sybase IQ support most (if not all) analytic/window functions you mention, Sybase ASE does not support said functions; a complete set of Sybase (now SAP) ASE documentation can be found here
